# Alfresco - Context Initialization Failed at startup process

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I have Alfresco Community Edition 5.2

I am getting the following error at catalina.out file, after computer restart

```
ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 03230000 Web Script Store
workspace://SpacesStore/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:extensionwebscripts must exist; multiple entries found.

at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore$1$1.execute(RepoStore.java:237)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore$1$1.execute(RepoStore.java:219)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore$1.doWork(RepoStore.java:218)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore$1.doWork(RepoStore.java:215)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore.getBaseNodeRef(RepoStore.java:214)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore.exists(RepoStore.java:289)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.SearchPath.getStores(SearchPath.java:110)
...    

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 03230000
Web Script Store workspace://SpacesStore/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:extensionwebscripts must exist; multiple entries found.
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore$1$1.execute(RepoStore.java:237)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore$1$1.execute(RepoStore.java:219)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore$1.doWork(RepoStore.java:218)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore$1.doWork(RepoStore.java:215)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore.getBaseNodeRef(RepoStore.java:214)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepoStore.exists(RepoStore.java:289)
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like someone has deleted a special folder in the Data Dictionary structure within the Alfresco Repository, which is hard-depended on within the startup process by the initialisation of web scripts. In this situation, it is hard to correct the issue without going back to a database backup where this structure still existed. Alternatively, you could customise the configuration of the web script lookup path and not depend on this particular folder any longer.

You can remove/disable the lookup of the web script extensions folder by putting the following bean in a Spring context file in `shared/classes/alfresco/extension/custom-web-context.xml`

```
<bean id="webscripts.searchpath"
   class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.SearchPath">
   <property name="searchPath">
      <list>
         <!-- This lookup in this store fails in your case -->
         <!-- <ref bean="webscripts.store.repo.extension" /> -->
         <!-- Comment the next line as well if you get a similar error
              afterwards, indicating you are also missing a second folder -->
         <ref bean="webscripts.store.repo" />
         <ref bean="webscripts.store.client.extension" />
         <ref bean="webscripts.store.client" />
         <ref bean="webscripts.store.alfresco" />
         <ref bean="webscripts.store" />
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: we have installation at /alfresco and the full path to new context is:  /alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/our-context.xml but the problem persist.

Comment: As discussed in #alfresco IRC, the Spring file must be custom-web-context.xml because the default load order overrides this specific bean when put in files of a different name. I'll update the answer.

Comment: We solve the problem with the suggestions of @AxelFaust and commenting `<ref bean="webscripts.store.repo" />` too in our case.

Comment: Thanks, now we can start Alfresco